How does one use groups or sub slash commands with Bot in discord.py?
I can't figure out how to configure sub-slash-commands or slash command groups using Bot in discord.py. I've tried various things I've read online, but this is what I have right now just trying to get any minimal thing to work:
intents: discord.Intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
fooGroup = discord.app_commands.Group(name='foo', description='foo!')

@fooGroup.command()
async def bar(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"bar")

bot.tree.add_command(fooGroup)

@bot.event
async def on_ready() -> None:
    await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=ServerId))
    print(f'{bot.user} is now running!')

bot.run(TOKEN)

It runs but I never see /foo show up. I was expecting or attempting to achieve something like:
/foo bar arg1 arg2 ...
/foo baz arg1 arg2 ...

My understanding is that foo is the root command or group and bar/baz are sub-commands but I haven't figured out how to make it happen.
I also tried using app_commands.CommandTree(bot) and @tree.command, which I have used previously for single-level slash commands, but I couldn't get that to work either...

The issue here is that you're syncing to a guild when you have no guild commands.
@fooGroup.command() # This is a global command

await bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=ServerId)) # However, you're syncing a to guild.

You either need to add the guilds= kwarg to the fooGroup.command() or remove the guild= in bot.tree.sync.

I get an error if I put any guild parameter into command(). I tried adding guild_ids (and also guild_only) to the fooGroup = ... line but that didn't help either. Removing all the guild stuff does work, as a global command, though I would prefer to be able to limit it.

Try creating a group like in the example given here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands%20group#group
